# Cant output a variable after 2 try:()

Tags: python, capture, verification

Here is my code:

```
def Serveur():

    import socket
    today = datetime.date.today()
    datename = str(today) + '.txt'
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = "192.168.1.245"
    port = 8000
    print (host)
    print (port)
    serversocket.bind((host, port))
    serversocket.listen(5)


    while True:
        (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
        print ("Connection Reussie")
        data = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
        print (data)  + "    RECU PAR ETHERNET"


        try:
            ver_file = open(datename, "r")
            for line in ver_file:
                if data in line:
                    filtre = line[-13:]
                    print filtre  + "MATCH TROUVE"
                    resultat = str(filtre)

        except:
             print ("Pas de match de produit captures aujourdhui")

    try:
        filtre_file = open("produit.txt", "r")
        for line in filtre_file:
            if resultat in line:
                convoyeur = line[-2:]
                print convoyeur

    except:
        print ("Erreur")
```

(Sorry if the indentation is bad, it messed up when I pasted it :( )
So my question is that my str convoyeur doesn't print at all! I dont know what is wrong in it!

Example of data variable that is received is 123456789012 (12 Characters barcode on ethernet barcode scanner)

Example of a line in produit.txt is:

```
123456789012 A
```

(The letter A is there for where the box need to go on a conveyor)

Comment: a few things, first of all, did you try printing `line`? did you try printing `resultat`? ... second, did you try to debugging it? third, are there any exceptions? fourth, I removed the offensive language as that will get you downvotes instantly. Please try to keep your questions PG and watch what you say.

Comment: Is an Exception being thrown? Also, you should fix the indentation seeing as the code is dependent on it.